# Hosted static files don't redirect if page unknown or redirect

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, react-router, router

This project is being build by Jenkins and hosted with static files. When I test it locally with `npm run start` it all works fine. However on production when the static files are hosted, I'm getting a `404` on redirect and on unknown pages.

Trying to debug this locally I setup a similar situation.

- Created the static files with `npm run build`
- Host the files locally with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

When I go to the simpleserver and go to non existing route `/thisdoesnotexist` I'm also getting a `404`.

I've tried using `HashRouter` which does not seem to fix anything. Besides I tried to use a `redirect` on the bottom of the `switch` to redirect the non existing routes the `/` if nothing is recognized. This does also not seem to work.

What is the best way to handle non existing routes and redirects in a static build?

Comment: For any request to the server, just send the React static files to browser. In express server you can do this by, `app.get('/*', (req,res) => res.send(path to react files))`

Answer (score 0):

To be precise it completely depends on how your system and infra are designed. But this is what I have seen mostly followed.

**Non-existing routes**: This type of pages are mostly handled inside your client-side router only which provision of first checking all the routes and if none matches then use one common component `404Component`.

**Static Routes**: For this type of route first you want to call from the server not from the browser and second on web server you want special rules for this type of route which returns to static pages instead of client application. I have used `nginx` for this kind of setup where all the static pages go to some `S3` pages and others to my client side router.

This type of setup should work

```
const reload = () => window.location.reload();

<Router>
  // all your client routes..
  ...

  // Your special static routes..
  <Route path="/sitemap.xml" onEnter={reload} />
  <Route path="/something.html" onEnter={reload} />
</Router>
```

Also, if you can put `target="_blank"` attribute in your `<Link>` that should also works

Comment: Well the issue is currently in the login flow. You login, you are returned back to the react app with /login#xxxxx. Locally this redirects just fine to /login but in production it results in the 404. So i don't think it will be possible to set a specific path with `.html` or something? Or can we use a wildcard there? `/login*.html`